# Unable to launch some Windows 10 apps

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-store-app, application-launch

I am unable to launch some apps in Windows 10. They never did launch in my account on my PC that I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, although they do work fine on another account on my PC that is an administrator (mine was a standard and I tried changing it to a admin but the apps still wont launch after). My symptoms of this issue are that when I click on the icon either in the pins list inside the start menu or the "All Apps" list nothing happens but an animation of the button pressing down and then up again.
I have tried running `sfc /scannow` and it gave me an output of:

```
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
supported in offline servicing scenarios.
```

and the [cbs.log file can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/43oq7m5n7duqyza/CBS.log?dl=0) although from what I have read through the extensive log it seems to be unrelated.

#### Apps Not Launching

- Xbox
- 3D Builder (which I have absolute no idea what it is)
- Weather
- People
- Get Started
- Calculator

And that is all of the apps so far that I have tried and failed to launch.

If anymore information is needed please let me know!

**UPDATE:** 
I also noticed that these apps also wont launch on another user with similar symptoms the only thing different is on this user when I click on the pinned app that doesn't work the app turns grey with a lighter coloured grey bar at the bottom of the icon, also when you click on them in the all apps menu they just show a grey bar at the bottom.

Thanks in advance!

Daniel

Comment: some files from update KB3081424 are damaged. remove this updates

Comment: @magicandre1981 How do I tell if I have this update and also how would I remove it if I do have it?

Comment: go to desktop control panel->programs & features->"installed updates" and remove the update.

Comment: You need to fix your system corruption before you do anything.  You need to run the DISM tool so SFC can actually resolve the problems it discovered.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would backup the OS in case something goes wrong. Here is how to do it natively: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5495-system-image-create-windows-10-a.html

Then, you can try removing the apps via right-click > uninstall or PowerShell commands: http://www.howtogeek.com/224798/how-to-uninstall-windows-10s-built-in-apps-and-how-to-reinstall-them/

Personally, I never tried that PowerShell command to restore all default apps at once, but I believe most if not all of those apps are re-installable via Windows Store anyhow.

Comment: Also in case something goes really wrong, creating a rescue media is a good idea: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4200-recovery-drive-create-windows-10-a.html

Comment: I just tried that with the Get Started app it still wont launch you can see a log of what I did here [link](http://pastebin.com/Vxh4DiSx).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what else to suggest other than re-installing the apps from the Windows Store instead of using that command.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Listing/Installing/Removing apps using:

```
DISM.exe /Online [/Get-ProvisionedAppxPackages | /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage | /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage | /Set-ProvisionedAppxDataFile]
```

Comment: it returns this error '/Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: how and what did you exactly execute with cmd or powershell, as administrator, manually or in a script etc.

Comment: Using PowerShell launched as an administator I get the error [link](http://pastebin.com/7pWVBWKd).

Comment: with "dism.exe /online /Get-ProvisionedAppxPackages" you list all packages. with "dism.exe /online /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackages" you can remove packages. with "dism.exe /online /Set-ProvisionedAppxDataFile" you add packages You cannot use them all in one line.

However take a look at: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html

Comment: Thanks for your help @Gio_sof but I got another error saying that the /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackages is an unknown option but I tried the command Repair-WindowsImage -Online -RestoreHealth found in that link and it gave me the error: `The restore operation failed. Either the repair source was not found
or the component store cannot be repaired.`